# I know this has been asked but I cannot get a function result. Create a unique list from duplicates

Tags: excel-formula

I know this has been asked and I have tried the formulas but cannot seem to get a functioning result. I have a spread sheet with many divisions but I would like to create  nonadjacent column with unique division names--no duplicates   here is an example of code I have tried

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$589, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($J$1:J1, $F$2:$F$589), 0)).
```

My total list of all divisions totals 588 one since each employees is in a division. I am seeking to create a non duplicates list - in a non adjacent column and then I can tally employees and other details related to individual division

I can send anyone a copy of my work if you can help

Comment: Are you putting this formula in J2?  Are you using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to exit edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

The formula should work if entered properly:

1. Paste the formula in the formula bar for J2. This will put Excel in edit mode.
2. Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter. This tells Excel that it is an Array formula.  If done properly Excel will put `{}` around the formula automatically.
3. Drag the formula down the sheet till it throws errors.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Mine shows a `0` because I do not have data in the whole range and the empty cells resolve to `0`.

Comment: That was the problem... appreciate it

Comment: @Jux please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.